# Launch Terminal via Python and run commands

Tags: python, ios, macos, terminal, appium

I am writing an automation script and it would be nice to be able to launch Terminal on my mac via my Python script in order to launch the Appium servers, instead of doing it manually.

The closest I've come is by using the following code, but this only launches Terminal and I am unable to send commands to it:

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

    Popen(['open', '-a', 'Terminal', '-n'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

I need to be able to launch two Terminal instances and run the following

1. 'appium'
2. 'appium -a 0.0.0.0 -p 4724'

Comment: Had deleted my comment and wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute shell commands in python like this:

```
import os

os.system('appium &')
```

this will start the Appium server

Comment: Terminal is not launched and I get 'sh: appium: command not found.'

Comment: this method won't launch terminal. this just execute your command.have you installed appium?

Comment: Appium is installed, this will launch appium in the background?

Comment: I would like to be able to see the output from Appium for debugging purposes, so Terminal needs to be visible. Can I use this in conjunction with  another command to do so?

Comment: This will show output for debugging. no need to new terminal tab.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `communicate` to send cmd to your terminal.

```
 from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

    p1 = Popen(['open', '-a', 'Terminal', '-n'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    p2 = Popen(['open', '-a', 'Terminal', '-n'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

    p1.communicate('appium')
    p2.communicate('appium -a 0.0.0.0 -p 4724')
```

Comment: Nothing is being sent to either Terminal window.